# как можно установить драйвер sqlsrv на Centos7 физически без командной строки

Tags: php, sql, linux, centos

На сервере стоит версия PHP 5
В проекте composer использует версию 7.3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Могу ли я залить драйверы для SQLSRV (SQL Server) именно для версии 7.3
С Линуксом Centos 7.9 раньше не работал, но проект горит и приходится понять в чем проблема
Думал есть ли возможность залить туда драйверы физически, или может есть способ прописать в командной строке нужное волшебство
Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

### Проблема старой версии PHP

composer не даст поставить пакеты для старой версии PHP.

Если просто залить файлы `vendor` со своего компьютера, код предназначенный для 7.3 практически наверняка не будет работать на 5 версии.

Поэтому без обновления PHP что-то делать дальше бесполезно.

Первый этап - обновить PHP, чуть ниже это делается. Либо использовать Docker.

### Как поставить драйверы для MSSQL

Вам потребуется доступ к консоли, а также root-права.

Есть 2 варианта.

1. [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org/userguide/php.html) - устаревший способ, проект заброшен. Точно работал на 5.6 версии, на новых - не знаю. Не тратьте время на него.
2. Использовать официальный драйвер от MS - об этом ниже.

[Вот инструкция](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-on-red-hat) для установки на Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL). Она подойдет также для CentOS - это бесплатный форк RHEL.

Я просто скопировал нужные части из руководства.

#### Шаг 1. Установка PHP (Red Hat)

```
sudo su
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php81
yum update
# Note: The php-pdo package is required only for the PDO_SQLSRV driver
yum install php php-pdo php-pear php-devel
```

Тут ставится PHP версии 8.1. Если нужна другая версия, замените в команде выше  `remi-php81` на `remi-php74`. Не знаю, есть ли версия для 7.3. Но код, написанный для 7.3 скорее всего будет работать на 7.4.

#### Шаг 2. Установка необходимых компонентов (Red Hat)

```
sudo su

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-release.repo

exit

sudo yum remove unixODBC-utf16 unixODBC-utf16-devel #to avoid conflicts
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y yum install -y msodbcsql18
```

Тут я убрал строчки относящиеся к RHEL 8, а также опциональные команды.

#### Шаг 3. Установка драйверов PHP для Microsoft SQL Server (Red Hat)

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
echo extension=sqlsrv.so >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/20-sqlsrv.ini
exit
```

ИЛИ можно также установить их из репозитория Remi:

```
sudo yum install php-sqlsrv
```

Остальные шаги 4, 5 - это установка Apache, его перезапуск и тестирование. Это опционально, у вас скорее всего уже стоит какой-то веб-сервер. После установки, его нужно перезапустить и попробовать подключиться.